# Why is there an "unsinkable disk" phenomenon? Is it related to the lift of the aircraft?

Tags: fluid-dynamics, fluid-statics, aerodynamics

A metal disk with a hole at its centre sinks in a container filled with water. When a vertical water jet hits the centre of the disc, it may float on the water surface. Explain this phenomenon and investigate the relevant parameters.

The disk is heavier than water. Why doesn't it sink to the bottom?

I think this is the result of the low pressure on the upper surface of the disk caused by the water level difference.

Comment: What research have you done yourself on this problem?

Comment: @AlNejati I think this is the result of the low pressure on the upper surface of the disk caused by the water level difference.

Answer (score 0):

I think this is the result of the low pressure on the upper surface of the disk caused by the water level difference.